# Why the scaled Image still occupy original width and height?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to append a scaled down image within a table cell. Somehow, the scaled image still occupy the original size.

This is what I have so far **(Updated)**

http://jsfiddle.net/qnUgx/1/

Code

```
<img style="display: block;width:250px;height:auto" src="http://www.ucmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/DinoArt-Logo.png"/>
```

If you notice there's gap between the 6th and 7th item which I believe the way I scale is still wrong. How can I remove the gap ?

The solution should also allow the content appear right away after the table.

Comment: The original image is 595px × 842px, it is displayed in your site as 250px × 354px.

Comment: You are scaling it correctly, it's just that the image is still taller than the rows in your table, causing the last row to be expanded. See @IrenPatel 's answer below for the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change your ROWSPAN size and remove your gap between 6th and 7th item.

Like this,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>The 7 main categories in Dino Art:</th>
        <td rowspan="9"><img style="display: block;width:250px;height:auto" src="http://www.ucmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/DinoArt-Logo.png"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>111111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>222222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3333333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>444444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>555555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>666666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>777777</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use img tag height width attribute as follows

```
 <td rowspan = 8><img   height = 100 width = 100 src="http://www.ucmas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/DinoArt-Logo.png"/> </td>
```